# logger при тестах junit

Tags: java, junit

Помогите понять.
У меня в pom.xml есть модули:

```
<!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--For Tests-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

плюс к этому там же я прописываю пути:

```
        <sourceDirectory> src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory> src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory> src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Вот рабочий класс:

```
public class Work {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    public void doSomething() {
      log.info("do something");
    }
...
}
```

Вот тестовый класс:

```
public class TestWork {

   @Test
   public void test() {
       Work work = new Work();
       work.doSomething();
   }
...
}
```

ну и в resources лежит log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/bitrix24.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %F:%M:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %t:%F:%M:%L - %m%n
```

ну и собственно вопрос:
Почему у меня нет логов, когда я запускаю тест???

Comment: `ну и в resources лежит log4j.properties` в рксурсах для основаного кода или в ресурсах для тестов?

Comment: @tym32167 в обоих